# How do I use the Filtered Throwables feature to filter stack traces in log4j2?

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, stack-trace

I'm using Java with Spring Boot and I'm tired of combing through stack traces with 100+ lines that I don't care about. Since I use log4j2 (v2.17.1), I followed the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) (search "Filtered Throwables"), which says:

---

#### Filtered Throwables

This example shows how to filter out classes from unimportant packages in stack traces.

```xml
<properties>
  <property name="filters">org.junit,org.apache.maven,sun.reflect,java.lang.reflect</property>
</properties>
...
<PatternLayout pattern="%m%xEx{filters(${filters})}%n"/>
```

The result printed to the console will appear similar to:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IllegalArgument
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowableTest.testException(ExtendedThrowableTest.java:72) [test-classes/:?]
... suppressed 26 lines
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)} [?:?]
... suppressed 3 lines
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null pointer
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowableTest.testException(ExtendedThrowableTest.java:71) ~[test-classes/:?]
... 30 more
```

---

So, following that example, my log4j2.xml looks like:

```xml
    <Properties>
        <Property name="EX_FILTERS">
            org.springframework,java.lang.reflect,sun.reflect
        </Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n%ex{filters(${EX_FILTERS})}
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
```

I'm sure it's parsing the PatternLayout because when I had a typo (`filter` instead of `filters`), I saw an error message on application startup.

Yet when I run my code, I still see every `org.springframework` stack trace line (and the`reflect` lines too). How do I successfully suppress those lines?

Comment: It appears the feature isn't implemented for `%ex` yet: https://lists.apache.org/thread/yoj9bdfqfph6q03t26r5mrdc37zjd9nw